# Проблема с выводом категории WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть Custom Post Type Продукты. Так же добавил кастомную таксономию, чтобы разделить их по категориям.

Сделал шаблон вывода taxonomy-catg.php для вывода шаблона категории
Но вот в чем проблема. Если я перехожу на страницу категории, а так же подкатегории у меня везде в url слаг товара. Как сделать урлы следующего вида:

А хочется чтобы был следующий вид:

Страница категории делает вывод дочерних подкатегории( на один уровень лишь) и когда мы уже переходим на страницу подкатегории там идет вывод самих товаров,

Пример:

site.ru/product-category/categoryOne - выводит список подкатегории
site.ru/product-category/categoryOne/podcategory - вывод товаров

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перепишите правила реврайтов. В **register_post_type** нужно добавить:

```
...
'rewrite' => [
    'slug'       => '%product_catg%', //product_catg - slug вашей категории
    'with_front' => false,
]
...
```

Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type#rewrite-massiv-logicheskij